# Passing data to Slim Renderer template PHP

Tags: php, templates, render, slim-3

I am using [Slim Framework v3](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/) and I have problems passing data from PHP to Slim templates.

For example:

```
$app->get('/user/{playerid}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {

    $playerid = $args['playerid'];

    $this->logger->info("Someone requested to see the score of the following player: [".$playerid."]");


    $db = Database::Instance();

    $row = $db->getPlayer($playerid);

    if ($row === false)
        return $this->renderer->render($response, 'dataNotFound.phtml', $args); // Not working: $playerid no displayed on HTML

    // Sets the player info on the template (this works)
    $args['name'] = $row['Name'];
    $args['language'] = $row['Language'];
    $args['score'] = $row['Score'];
    $args['card'] = $row['CardPngBase64'];

    return $this->renderer->render($response, 'user.phtml', $args);
});
```

The working template (`./templates/user.phtml`) is:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 4%">

    <?php
    if (isset($playerid) && isset($name) && isset($language) && isset($score) && isset($card)) : ?>
        <h1 class="jumbotron"><img align="center" src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($card); ?>" /><br> <?= htmlspecialchars($name); ?>'s scores </h1>


        <div class="row text-center">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Country</th>
                    <th scope="col">Score</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($name); ?></td>
                    <td><?= htmlspecialchars(Locale::getDisplayRegion('-'.$language, 'en')); ?></td>
                    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($score); ?></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <h1 style="color: darkred">⛔️ Internal error: can't get the players data.</h1>
    <?php endif; ?>


    <div class="row" style="position: relative; margin-top: 50%">
        <a class="text-justify" href="http://responseable.csp.it">Go back to the main page</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

The **not** working template (`./templates/dataNotFound.phtml`) is:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 4%">
    <h1 class="jumbotron">‍♂️ Player not found ‍♀️</h1>

    <hr style="margin-top: 5%; margin-bottom: 5%">

    <div class="row">
        <p>‼️</p>
        <br>
        <p>The player <?php if(isset($playerid)) htmlspecialchars($playerid) ?> does not exists, please retry.</p>

    </div>

    <div class="row" style="position: relative; margin-top: 50%">
        <a class="text-justify" href="http://responseable.csp.it">Go back to the main page</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

So, when `$playerid` is found by the database, it returns a correct rendered template (user.phtml) and it shows correctly the player data.

But when the ID is not found by the database, the rendering of dataNotFound.phtml doesn't work, in particular, I can see correctly all the HTML page, but `htmlspecialchars($playerid)` is missing or empty.

---

It's probably a small mistake, but I can't find it. Can someone help me? However, I am new in Slim.

Comment: Are you sure `$args['playerid']` is set? If you put `var_dump($args)` before render `dataNotFound.phtml`, what is the output?

Comment: This line will never print something: `<?php if(isset($playerid)) htmlspecialchars($playerid) ?>` try `<?php if(isset($playerid)) echo htmlspecialchars($playerid); ?>`

Comment: Dumping `$args` **before** of `return $this->renderer->render($response, 'user.phtml', $args);` showed me the data I expected.

Comment: Thank you @DanielO, that solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like.

- Router file

  $this->renderer->args = array(
    'pid' => $args['pid'],   );
     return $this->renderer->render($response, "user.phtml");
- ./templates/dataNotFound.phtml

echo $this->args['pid'];

Answer (score 0):

routes.php

```php
$app->get('/panel',function(Request $request, Response $response, array $args) use ($container){
    return $container->get('renderer')->render($response, 'panel.phtml', [
        'key' => "val"
    ]);
});
```

panel.phtml

```php
<?php print_r($data); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
...
```